# LVM module from puppet forge randomly breaks applying manifest

Tags: redhat, puppet

When using the lvm module, we get an "Invalid parameter size_is_minsize" randomly.  If we restart puppet master, the error goes away for a while but then comes back. This is on Scientific Linux 6.6 (RHEL6 derivative). puppet-3.7.2-1.el6.noarch on the client. Foreman 1.7.2 on server...

```
[root@lnx586 ~]# puppet agent -t
Warning: Local environment: "production" doesn't match server specified node environment "dev", switching agent to "dev".
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Invalid parameter size_is_minsize on Logical_volume[tmp] at /mnt/puppet/etc/environments/dev/modules/sge/manifests/init.pp:10 on node lnx586
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

#### Restart puppet master.

```
[root@lnx586 ~]# puppet agent -t
Warning: Local environment: "production" doesn't match server specified node environment "dev", switching agent to "dev".
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Info: Caching catalog for lnx586
Info: Applying configuration version '1424461702'
Notice: Finished catalog run in 15.46 seconds

[root@lnx586 ~]# puppet agent -t
Warning: Local environment: "production" doesn't match server specified node environment "dev", switching agent to "dev".
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Info: Caching catalog for lnx586
Info: Applying configuration version '1424461767'
Notice: Finished catalog run in 15.69 seconds

[root@lnx586 ~]# puppet agent -t
Warning: Local environment: "production" doesn't match server specified node environment "dev", switching agent to "dev".
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Invalid parameter size_is_minsize on Logical_volume[tmp] at /mnt/puppet/etc/environments/dev/modules/sge/manifests/init.pp:10 on node lnx586
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

Comment: Can you show us what's in that `modules/sge/manifests/init.pp` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turned out to be using the dev -> prod testing - we had different modules and more importantly, a different lib from LVM between dev and prod. See:
https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-731
for the bug in puppet that causes this.